# How to assign an object function to a variable?

Tags: php

```
class example()
{
    function shout($var)
    {
        echo 'shout'.$var;
    }

    function whisper($var, $bool)
    {
        if($bool)
        {
           echo $var;
        }
    }
}

$obj = new example();

if($var) 
{
    $func = $obj->shout();
}else
{
    $func = $obj->whisper();
}
```

I want to prepare the function variable first for later use instead of putting conditions in a loop. Is there a possible way to do it?

Comment: Careful with the arguments on whisper/shout/etc.  You're playing with quacks-like-a-duck fire.

Comment: @landons I don't see how there is any "quacks-like-a-duck" fire, considering it (PHP) is all dynamically typed anyway...

Comment: @landons really? i didn't even noticed it hehe

Comment: @pst: very true.  I'm more hinting at how hard it would be to debug if this approach grows more complex over time.  It seems better to have the object class be the dynamic part, and always call the same method.  That way, you could enforce the idea that the called method REQUIRES a certain context, arguments, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the function name in a string:

```
if($var) 
{
    $func = 'shout';
}else
{
    $func = 'whisper';
}
```

Later on:

```
$obj->$func
```

---

You can also use a callback:

```
if($var)
{
    $func = array($obj, 'shout');
}else
{
    $func = array($obj, 'whisper');
}
```

Later:

```
call_user_func($func);
```

or:

```
call_user_func_array($func, $args);
```

Comment: @notJim, which one is more advisable to use?

Comment: @pst: This is a callback according to [the php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php).
@kaz: I don't have a strong opinion either way. I usually use the `$obj->$func` one, unless I need to pass it around to other functions.

Comment: @notJim It was a bit of tongue-in-cheak on my part: I guess I should have instead emphasized that it (the second approach) is "a tuple of information to invoke a method by name" and not a first-class value (or callback function) :)

Answer (score 7):

You can call methods by name:

```
if ($var) {
    $fn = 'shout';
} else {
    $fn = 'whisper';
}

$obj->$fn();
```

Comment: Yes (+1) you can, but this technically isn't what the question is asking :-) In Ruby and Python it is possible to get "bound methods" (functions associated with an object context), while C# has method groups that are convertible to delegates (also associated with an object context in this case), for instance. Is there any such concept with PHP? (Say, 5.3)

Comment: @pst i think there's no php counterpart of bound method - we'll i've been looking for it. PHP is really an old language, we're just lucky because it's flexible that programmers can do numbers of work around.

Comment: @pst: There is not. PHP didn't have function objects _at all_ until the release of PHP 5.3 -- heck, `create_function` still returns a gensym -- and even with those there's no way to get a function object for a defined function of any variety, let alone a bound method.

Comment: @duskwuff: what is a gensym? I have never heard this term before.

Comment: **Gen**erated **sym**bol. In this case, a string with the name of the function which `create_function` created, following the pattern "lambda_#".